# Как выбрать систему хранения данных innodb?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, wordpress

На одном хостинге, при создании таблиц в базе данных, по умолчанию создаются таблицы myisam. И дело в том, что это нигде нельзя выбрать, чтобы по умолчанию создавались innodb.
Подскажите, как создавать таблицы innodb? т.е. допустим я устанавливаю wordpress и мне нужно, чтобы создавались таблицы innodb, а по умолчанию создаются myisam.
Можно ли как-то после установки wordpress, переопределить таблицы из myisam в innodb ?

---

Сейчас есть возможность проверить только на локальном сервере, на котором только innodb.
Взял код из приведённой ниже ссылки, и пытался конвертировать из innodb в myisam, но код почему-то не работает. Подскажите, что не так?

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB'
AND table_schema = 'mydatabase';
```

второй код:

```
SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'name_of_your_db';

SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=MyISAM;') AS sql_statements
FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
WHERE   table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME
AND     `ENGINE` = 'InnoDB'
AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name DESC;
```

естественно название бд ставил правильное:
в 1м коде table_schema = 'mydatabase';
во 2м SET @DATABASE_NAME = 'name_of_your_db';
в этом участке кода ставил свою бд

Comment: Может тут https://www.opennet.ru/tips/1958_mysql_myisam_innodb.shtml советы помогут вам?

Comment: через что у вас доступ к бд? phpMyAdmin или SQLyog?

Comment: доступ через phpMyAdmin, т.е. у меня есть полный доступ к админке на хостинге, но это нигде нельзя настроить, чтобы были по умолчанию innodb

Comment: Про конвертацию туда/назад вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb

Comment: @nick_n_a, благодарю за ссылку, но код почему-то не работает. Дополнил вопрос, подскажите, что не так?

Comment: конвертации не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать новую базу с двихком "InnoDB" можно так:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  (id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Поменять старую:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

```
ALTER TABLE old_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

PS:

В вашем коде вариант

1. Вы выбирете таблицы с `innodb` и создаете строку которая меняет их на `MyISAM`.
2. вы так же выбераете `innodb` таблицы и создаете запрос который меняет их на `innodb`.

**Ну и запрос(строку) который вам вернёт надо запустить!**

Дополнил ваш вариант(
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
)

Меняем все `innodb` на `MyISAM`

```
SET @queryString = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME, " ENGINE='MyISAM';") SEPARATOR '') 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE ENGINE= 'InnoDB'
        AND table_schema = "mydatabase"
);

PREPARE q FROM @queryString;
EXECUTE q;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE q;
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE old_table ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: это получается нужно каждую таблицу отдельно конвертировать?
А почему вышеприведённый код не работает?

Comment: создавать таблице мне не нужно, таблицы создаются вордпрессом, но они создаются в myisam. 
В принципе вариант ALTER TABLE old_table ENGINE=InnoDB; подходит, но хотелось-бы узнать, почему не работает вышеприведённый код

Comment: @word Дополнил ответ.

Comment: что-то не сходится.
пример из 1го кода выполняет множественный вызов комадн alter tabel ...

Comment: что там ещё нужно запускать?

Comment: @word Одинарные ковычки не нравились. Обновил.

Comment: @word Сработало?

Comment: нет, та же ошибка

Comment: @word `;` после `AND table_schema = "mydatabase"` лишняя была. Глупая ошибка...

Comment: теперь mysql говорит: "Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи"